# Export data to excel, only getting last line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When using my code, I'm only getting the last result. I know it's because it's replacing each result, but what should I do instead?

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("scoreboardInfoNames")
poster = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("outcomeCollection")

for post in posts, poster:
    data = pd.DataFrame({"Teams": [post.text], "Odds": [poster.text]})


datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter("Matches.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")

data.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name="Sheet1")

datatoexcel.save()
```

I want it to be like this

```
  Teams          Odds
  Team1         Odds1
  Team2         Odds2
  Team3         Odds3
    .             .
    .             .
    .             .
```

Comment: Take a very close look at your code and think what happens to `data` in every iteration of the loop

Comment: Yes, it's getting replaced by each result, but how do I make a new dataframe for each result?

Comment: Use a list/tuple? Do the processing inside the loop?